# Mockito not resetting

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a tests, that when they run individually work fine. However when i run them together one always fail expecting total invocations accross both tests rather than one.

I have added Mockito.reset in the before and after method, but to no avail.

```
    private Logic mockTest = Mockito.mock(Logic.class);         

    @Before
    public void createMocks() {
        Mockito.reset(mockTest);
    }

    @Test
    public void TestGameList() {


        Mockito.when(mockTest.getGame()).thenReturn(null);

            Mockito.verify(mockTest, Mockito.times(1)).getGame();

    }

    @Test
    public void TestGame2List() {


        Mockito.when(mockTest.getGame()).thenReturn(null);

            Mockito.verify(mockTest, Mockito.times(1)).getGame();

    }
```

Why doesnt reset work?

I have tried VerificationModeFactory to count it, but that doesnt work either

Comment: Make sure that `createMocks()` method actually gets called.

Comment: When you're running this with JUnit, there should not be any need for your `createMocks` method. JUnit creates a new class instance for each test. So as long as the field `mockTest` is not static, you will have a fresh mock for each test. No need for `reset()`. However, both tests as you've written them here should fail, because there are no calls to `mockTest` whatsoever. (`when(mockTest.getGame()).thenReturn(...)` is only stubbing, this is not a call to `getGame()`).

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the following:

```
@Mock
private Logic mockTest;         

@Before
public void createMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotiation.initMocks(this);
}
```

or

```
private Logic mockTest;      

@Before
public void createMocks() {
    mockTest = Mockito.mock(Logic.class); 
}
```

Either way you will create an entirely new mock for each test thereby ensuring that no state is maintained across tests.